# Spark Context creation error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I get the following set of errors when trying to create a spark context from my application.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.<init>(SparkConf.scala:723)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:571)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.setAppName(SparkConf.scala:118)
        at sparkEnvironment$.<init>(Ticket.scala:33)
        at sparkEnvironment$.<clinit>(Ticket.scala)
        at Ticket$.main(Ticket.scala:40)
        at Ticket.main(Ticket.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 10 more
```

I'm using Spark 2.2.0 and Scala version 2.12.3. My build.sbt looks like follows :

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"

//Sparks dependencies
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.2.0"
```

And the snippet in which I try to create the context is as follows :

```
object sparkEnvironment {

  Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
  Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty.server").setLevel(Level.OFF)

  val conf : SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Ticketing").setMaster("local[2]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
}

object Ticket {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println(sc)
}
}
```

Comment: define the sparkContext inside main method and you should be fine.

Comment: Nope didn't work either.

Comment: Actually my problem is that, Spark Context is created without any error in Spark Shell and runs the code, but when it comes to creating in the application (spark context), it throws exceptions.

Comment: add provided in your sbt dependencies as in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.2.0

Comment: Now the refresh error is : [error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-tags, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common

Comment: and :  [error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.apache.spark:spark-launcher, org.json4s:json4s-ast, org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle, com.twitter:chill, org.json4s:json4s-jackson, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala, org.json4s:json4s-core, org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe, org.apache.spark:spark-tags, org.apache.spark:spark-core, org.apache.spark:spark-network-common

Comment: delete the `scalaVersion := "2.12.3"` line from sbt

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please move your comments containing log files into the question itself, so they are easily viewed by readers seeing the question for the first time. They can be formatted using the code tool.

Comment: @TheShark I have had similar looking errors before, try moving the creation of the context to outside the main method but inside the `Ticker` object and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark 2.2.0 is built and distributed to work with Scala 2.11 by default.
To write applications in Scala, you will need to use a compatible Scala version (e.g. 2.11.X).
And your scala version is 2.12.X. That's why it is throwing exception.